# directive scope does not update after ng-click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive where `$scope.awards` is empty on load:

```
 .directive('awardNavBar', function () {
     // Directive used to display a badge.
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                awards: '='
            },
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: "/static/html/partials/directives/awardNavBar.html",
            controller: function ($scope) {
                    console.log($scope.awards)
            }
        }
    })
```

However, when a user clicks my controller fires a call and updates $scope.awards with content:

```
   .controller("awardController", ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Restangular', "$q", "$location", "TokenRestangular",
        function ($scope, $rootScope, Restangular, $q, $location, TokenRestangular) {

            $scope.updateAwardScope = function () {
                resource = TokenRestangular.all('award');
                resource.getList()
                    .then(function (awards) {
                        $scope.awards = awards;
                    })
            }

        }])
```

My problem is that the the directive scope.awards stays blank and never gets updated.

Is there a way I can call the directive from the controller and update it's scope?

I have tried:

$scope.$apply()  but get the error:

**[$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest**

This is my html:

first the click event:

```
  <div ng-controller="awardController">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right" >
            <div ng-click="toggle('rightSidebar'); updateAwardScope()" class="btn btn-navbar">
                <i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Chat
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then my directive:

```
  <div ng-controller="awardController">
                     <award-nav-bar awards="awards"></award-nav-bar>
                </div>
```

Comment: Try to `console.log(awards)` and tell us what shows up.

Comment: Show your html binding.

Comment: @DaniloValente all my objects: [Object, Object, count: 2, next: null, previous: null, route: "award", getRestangularUrl: function…]

Comment: @Spike Great. Now as Chandermani suggested, please show your HTML binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it seems that you are not wrapping `awards` in `{{ }}` in your HTML binding. Try this:

```
<award-nav-bar awards="{{ awards }}"></award-nav-bar>
```

Otherwise, the `awards` attribute will equal to the string `"awards"`.

Comment: I see, now that makes sense. However the scope still does not update. Is this where I now use apply()? will this still give the error.. [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: Are you sure it really doesn't update? It might be not being showed. Anyway, can you post it to a Plnkr?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the solution is none of what you got, i did a directive with isolate scope to one model from controller  then in directive using the rectangular to get files from server, i just try to update it using the normal: scope.myDirective = restdata, it works well on directive but do not update the scope in controller, i try to use $apply but it throw an error that is already in process, then i finally use angular.extend and that save my world!, since rectangular has it's one scope it only updates to the first parent, the directive controller, and the main controller is never updated. that's what angular.extend fix.

Let me know if that helps you

Comment: There's already an answer accepted by the original poster to this question. If you want to critique that answer, it might be better to do it as a comment rather than your critique as a new answer.